# Return a Tree Map using streams in Java 11

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader, treemap

I am creating a function that reads a .txt file and returns a tree maps as Tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file", "fileName.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    Map<Integer, Long> wordLengthCount = lines.map(l -> l.split(" ")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.length(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Just pass in a mapFactory, a supplier providing a new empty Map into which the results will be inserted. You can merely use a constructor reference as shown here to get the work done. Also notice that this is an overload of the `groupingBy` function.

As mentioned below in the comment, this can further be simplified using a method reference in place of lambda,

```
Map<Integer, Long> wordLengthCount = lines.map(l -> l.split(" ")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

Coming back to your context, I would suggest you to pass in the file path to the method and it will return you the `Map`. So here's how it looks in practice.

```
public static Map<Integer, Long> wordCountByLength(String path) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        return lines.map(l -> l.split(" ")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the method reference `String::length` for the first argument to `groupingBy`.

Comment: I updated my question with your code, I'm still getting errors. Could you assist me?

Comment: What are the errors you are facing. You have include them in the question.

Comment: You have to use `reader.lines()` since you are using a `BufferedReader`

Comment: I updated it with that and updated my code and error message, I seem to have 'error: cannot find symbol' errors.

Comment: What is the Java version you are using? It should be java8 or higher.

Comment: I just updated my question including the test I run on the function, now I'm only getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError" would this make it easier to find a solution?

Comment: This test passes. `@Test
 public void testCount() throws Exception {
  // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.txt"));
  Map<Integer, Long> actual = FilePaths.wordCountByLength("src/main/resources/data.txt");
  Map<Integer, Long> expected = Map.of(2, 1L, 3, 2L, 6, 1L);
  assert actual.equals(expected);
 }`

Comment: Could it be maybe that it's not returning a long value?